# SKSpriteNode moving along a vector

Tags: swift, vector, sprite-kit

If an `SKSpriteNode` runs an `SKAction` telling it to move by a certain vector for a duration, will the `SKSpriteNode` still have momentum and keep moving once the action is complete? Also, if another action is called telling the node to move along a different vector while it is still moving by the first vector, will the node listen to only the second vector, only the first, or both? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SKAction`s and the physics are separate. The action will run and ignore all of the physics, and the previous vector. You should use `applyForce` if you want it to move by a certain amount.

Comment: I mean I said myNode.runAction(SKAction.moveBy(CGVector, duration: 1.0)), and before one second had passed, I called a similar action with a different vector

Comment: so by ignore the previous vector, it basically terminates the previous vector? And also if it is moving by a vector is its momentum still zero?

Comment: Yes I believe it terminates the previous vector. If a vector is terminated the velocity is therefore 0, which means momentum is zero because momentum = mass * velocity.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation